# CSS stacking order - how to get this right?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I have written the code below to help me understand CSS stacking order but I am stuck.
In the page below when I hover over the link "Three" (id=link_three), I want the sub-menu to appear.
The sub-menu appears but the menubar gets distorted because the sub-menu is not stacked above the rest of the menubar. What are the stacking contexts and stacking orders here? And what is the proper way to make the sub-menu appear one level above?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<!--
* {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menubar_ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.menubar_ul_li,.menubar_ul_li_menu {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.menu_ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

.menu_ul_li {

}

#link_three:hover>#menu_three {
    display: block;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="top_menubar" class="menubar_ul">
        <li class="menubar_ul_li" id="link_one">One</li>
        <li class="menubar_ul_li" id="link_two">Two</li>
        <li class="menubar_ul_li_menu" id="link_three"><a href="#">Three</a>
            <ul class="menu_ul" id="menu_three">
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_one">One</li>
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_two">Two</li>
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_three">
                <!-- This is intentional: -->
                Threeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</li>
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_four">Four</li>
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_five">Five</li>
                <li class="menu_ul_li" id="menuitem_six">Six</li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class="menubar_ul_li" id="link_four">Four</li>
        <li class="menubar_ul_li" id="link_five">Five</li>
        <li class="menubar_ul_li" id="link_six">Six</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add "position:absolute" or set width to #menu_three http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/v2eHs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Just add "position:absolute;" to your css, this is going to be then -->

#link_three:hover>#menu_three {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: i did but i dont have 15 reputation yet